# How to create a Midlet SVG with a Data Base in J2ME

Tags: java, java-me, svg, midp, netbeans-7

I need to know how I can do one application with SVG Netbeans and it work with a Data Base for a Midlet app. And then I have a problem with tutorial of SVG for Netbeans because I create the SVG and I can't see it in the visualmidlet screen.

Comment: what code do you use to create SVG?

Comment: Have you seen this screencast? http://netbeans.org/kb/docs/javame/svgtouch-screencast.html

Comment: This forum really work, i dont see again because i forget it :/. Really i have problem with this screencast Telmo. But i have to say that study my options for mobile development i quit to JME and SVG and now i use framework Sencha Touch and PhoneGap and all is better ^^.